# Execute JS inside of a return call

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react and I have this inside of a class components return statement(not all code):

```
            <CollapseBody>
              { el.details.map(item => (
                this.displayListItemComponent(item)
              ))}
            </CollapseBody>
```

I am able run a map since it's jsx and my map method is inside the brackets {}.
Then outside my return statement I have:

```
  displayListItemComponent = item => {
      return(
        <CollapseHeader style={styles.concernsCollapseTitle}>
          <Separator bordered>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{item.name}</Text>
          </Separator>
        </CollapseHeader>
      )
}
```

That works fine.  However I need to run another map on some other data from state.

```
  return(
    <CollapseHeader style={styles.concernsCollapseTitle}>
      <Separator bordered>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{item.name}</Text>
      </Separator>
    </CollapseHeader>
    {
      concernsInDB[item.values].map(el => console.log(el));
    }
  )
```

This does not work.  Neither does removing the brackets from the map statement.  My intended behavior is to loop through the data in `concernsInDB[item.values]` and return some dynamic listItems.  Something like this:

return(
    
      
        {item.name}
      
    
      concernsInDB[item.values].map(el => {
        
        {el.name}
        
      });
  )
Any idea how I can achieve this?

Update error added:
[image]

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must return only one parent node.

So, you may want to wrap your component into a `<div>` or a `<Fragment>`:

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <CollapseHeader style={styles.concernsCollapseTitle}>
      <Separator bordered>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{item.name}</Text>
      </Separator>
    </CollapseHeader>
    {concernsInDB[item.values].map(el => { { el.name } })}
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: Not *strictly* true, you can return an array (assuming React v16+)

Comment: Ya according to docs react v16+ can return an array with React.Fragment.  None the less this helped me so marking as correct and THANK YOU!  @Fcmam5

Answer (score 1):

1. React only supports returning a single root element in the return of a render method. Have you tried wrapping your elements in an outer `<div>`?

```js
return (
 <>
  <CollapseHeader style={styles.concernsCollapseTitle}>
   <Separator bordered>
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{item.name}</Text>
    </Separator>
  </CollapseHeader>
  {
   concernsInDB[item.values].map(el => console.log(el));
  }
 </>
)
```

2. Coding style is up to you, however, it is more common to return JSX from a React component instead of a regular function as you do in your example.

Declare outside of your class (maybe even another file): (Notice the capital **D**)

```js
const DisplayListItemComponent = item => {
 return(
  <CollapseHeader style={styles.concernsCollapseTitle}>
   <Separator bordered>
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{item.name}</Text>
   </Separator>
  </CollapseHeader>
 )
}
```

Usage:

```js
<CollapseBody>
 { el.details.map(item => (
  <DisplayListItemComponent item={item} />
 ))}
</CollapseBody>
```

Does this work for you?